# Android Kotlin - Sum of JSON objects

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I have two JSON files which are connected using foreign key/field (in my case one is Post( id, ...) and Comments ( postId, ...)). I need to display total number of comments per post (in my case it's always 5).

My data classes are as follows:

```
data class Posts(val userId: Int,
                 val id: Int,
                 val title: String,
                 val body: String)

data class Comments(val postId: Int,
                    val id: Int,
                    val name: String,
                    val email: String,
                    val body: String)
```

And here is the function which I use to get json data (I use okhttp for setting up the client and gson for getting the data):

```
private fun fetchCommentJson() {
        val postId = intent.getIntExtra(POST_ID, -1)
        val commentJsonData = commentsJSON

        val client = OkHttpClient()

        val request = Request.Builder().url(commentJsonData).build()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                toast("Something went wrong fetching your data")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                val body = response?.body()?.string()
                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                val commentsDetail = gson.fromJson(body, Array<Comments>::class.java)
                val postDetail = gson.fromJson(body, Array<Posts>::class.java)

                runOnUiThread {

                    for (commentSizeList in 0 until commentsDetail.size) {

                        val listOfComments = commentsDetail[commentSizeList] // List of all comments by Index
                        val post = postDetail[postId - 1].id // Post Id

                        // If postId is equal to original post id
                        if (listOfComments.postId == post) {
                            // Print it out
                            println(listOfComments)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

When I print out the list, it really does print out all the comments per particular post based on it's ID (since comparison it's done). However it prints out each comment separately (and setting listOfComments.size prints out 1 for each comment).

[displaying list of all comments per post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlui7.jpg)

My question is how to combine them all, so it displays total number of comments per post (in this case -> 5)?

Comment: Your question is little bit unclear. You need to display number of comments per post but you know that is always 5 comments?

Comment: @Yupi JSON files are already generically made. I'll pass the links to them here:

Posts: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
Comments: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments

But yes, there are 5 comments per post and since I can't hardcode the value it needs to be dynamically made. Like I said, I get a list of those comments (however they're printed out separately), I just need to add them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I would do this is like this:

```
val totalNumberOfCommentsForPost = commentsDetail?.filter {
    it.postId == post
}?.size ?: 0
```

`.filter` only selects the comments with the same post id.

Then `.size` gets hows many are in the new filtered list.

And finally as a safety precaution `?: 0` if any of these functions return null then return 0.

Comment: Thank you so much for both solution itself and explaining it, this worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need correctly, you could replace your entire for loop with this code using [`filter`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html):

```
// Post Id, the way you've been calculating it
val post = postDetail[postId - 1].id 

// a list of comments only containing the ones that have the ID you need
val filteredComments: List<Comments> = commentsDetail.filter { it.postId == post }
```

From here, you can print either the entire list:

```
println(filteredComments)
```

Or the size of the list:

```
println(filteredComments.size)
```